# How to decide which stencil shader instance overwrites the other one?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, shader

in our game, we have a stencil shader for shadows. However, as the player moves to the shadows, the player shadow overwrites the tree shadows, resulting in the player feet not being in the shadows (since player shadow is underneath the player sprite).

My question: is there a way to define which shader instance overwrites which one? If I could define it, then I could choose that the tree shadows overwrite the player shadow, and the problem would be solved. Other suggestions are welcome as well!

[Visualization of what happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEgpt.png)

[Snipped of the shader code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDxJr.png)

Here's the full shader code

```
Shader "Custom/test_StencilAlpha"
{
    Properties
    {
        // Specular vs Metallic workflow
        _WorkflowMode("WorkflowMode", Float) = 1.0

        [MainTexture] _BaseMap("Albedo", 2D) = "white" {}
        [MainColor] _BaseColor("Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)

        _Cutoff("Alpha Cutoff", Range(0.0, 1.0)) = 0.5

        _Smoothness("Smoothness", Range(0.0, 1.0)) = 0.5
        _SmoothnessTextureChannel("Smoothness texture channel", Float) = 0

        _Metallic("Metallic", Range(0.0, 1.0)) = 0.0
        _MetallicGlossMap("Metallic", 2D) = "white" {}

        _SpecColor("Specular", Color) = (0.2, 0.2, 0.2)
        _SpecGlossMap("Specular", 2D) = "white" {}

        [ToggleOff] _SpecularHighlights("Specular Highlights", Float) = 1.0
        [ToggleOff] _EnvironmentReflections("Environment Reflections", Float) = 1.0

        _BumpScale("Scale", Float) = 1.0
        _BumpMap("Normal Map", 2D) = "bump" {}

        _Parallax("Scale", Range(0.005, 0.08)) = 0.005
        _ParallaxMap("Height Map", 2D) = "black" {}

        _OcclusionStrength("Strength", Range(0.0, 1.0)) = 1.0
        _OcclusionMap("Occlusion", 2D) = "white" {}

        [HDR] _EmissionColor("Color", Color) = (0,0,0)
        _EmissionMap("Emission", 2D) = "white" {}

        _DetailMask("Detail Mask", 2D) = "white" {}
        _DetailAlbedoMapScale("Scale", Range(0.0, 2.0)) = 1.0
        _DetailAlbedoMap("Detail Albedo x2", 2D) = "linearGrey" {}
        _DetailNormalMapScale("Scale", Range(0.0, 2.0)) = 1.0
        [Normal] _DetailNormalMap("Normal Map", 2D) = "bump" {}

        // SRP batching compatibility for Clear Coat (Not used in Lit)
        [HideInInspector] _ClearCoatMask("_ClearCoatMask", Float) = 0.0
        [HideInInspector] _ClearCoatSmoothness("_ClearCoatSmoothness", Float) = 0.0

        // Blending state
        _Surface("__surface", Float) = 0.0
        _Blend("__blend", Float) = 0.0
        _Cull("__cull", Float) = 2.0
        [ToggleUI] _AlphaClip("__clip", Float) = 0.0
        [HideInInspector] _SrcBlend("__src", Float) = 1.0
        [HideInInspector] _DstBlend("__dst", Float) = 0.0
        [HideInInspector] _ZWrite("__zw", Float) = 1.0

        [ToggleUI] _ReceiveShadows("Receive Shadows", Float) = 1.0
        // Editmode props
        _QueueOffset("Queue offset", Float) = 0.0

        // ObsoleteProperties
        [HideInInspector] _MainTex("BaseMap", 2D) = "white" {}
        [HideInInspector] _Color("Base Color", Color) = (1, 1, 1, 1)
        [HideInInspector] _GlossMapScale("Smoothness", Float) = 0.0
        [HideInInspector] _Glossiness("Smoothness", Float) = 0.0
        [HideInInspector] _GlossyReflections("EnvironmentReflections", Float) = 0.0

        [HideInInspector][NoScaleOffset]unity_Lightmaps("unity_Lightmaps", 2DArray) = "" {}
        [HideInInspector][NoScaleOffset]unity_LightmapsInd("unity_LightmapsInd", 2DArray) = "" {}
        [HideInInspector][NoScaleOffset]unity_ShadowMasks("unity_ShadowMasks", 2DArray) = "" {}
    }

    SubShader
    {
        // Universal Pipeline tag is required. If Universal render pipeline is not set in the graphics settings
        // this Subshader will fail. One can add a subshader below or fallback to Standard built-in to make this
        // material work with both Universal Render Pipeline and Builtin Unity Pipeline
        Tags{"RenderType" = "Opaque" "RenderPipeline" = "UniversalPipeline" "UniversalMaterialType" = "Lit" "IgnoreProjector" = "True" "ShaderModel"="4.5"}
        LOD 300

        Stencil {
            Ref 1
            Comp Greater
            Pass Replace
        }

        // ------------------------------------------------------------------
        //  Forward pass. Shades all light in a single pass. GI + emission + Fog
        Pass
        {
            // Lightmode matches the ShaderPassName set in UniversalRenderPipeline.cs. SRPDefaultUnlit and passes with
            // no LightMode tag are also rendered by Universal Render Pipeline
            Name "ForwardLit"
            Tags{"LightMode" = "UniversalForward"}

            Blend[_SrcBlend][_DstBlend]
            ZWrite[_ZWrite]
            Cull[_Cull]

            HLSLPROGRAM
            #pragma exclude_renderers gles gles3 glcore
            #pragma target 4.5

            // -------------------------------------
            // Material Keywords
            #pragma shader_feature_local _NORMALMAP
            #pragma shader_feature_local _PARALLAXMAP
            #pragma shader_feature_local _RECEIVE_SHADOWS_OFF
            #pragma shader_feature_local _ _DETAIL_MULX2 _DETAIL_SCALED
            #pragma shader_feature_local_fragment _SURFACE_TYPE_TRANSPARENT
            #pragma shader_feature_local_fragment _ALPHATEST_ON
            #pragma shader_feature_local_fragment _ALPHAPREMULTIPLY_ON
            #pragma shader_feature_local_fragment _EMISSION
            #pragma shader_feature_local_fragment _METALLICSPECGLOSSMAP
            #pragma shader_feature_local_fragment _SMOOTHNESS_TEXTURE_ALBEDO_CHANNEL_A
            #pragma shader_feature_local_fragment _OCCLUSIONMAP
            #pragma shader_feature_local_fragment _SPECULARHIGHLIGHTS_OFF
            #pragma shader_feature_local_fragment _ENVIRONMENTREFLECTIONS_OFF
            #pragma shader_feature_local_fragment _SPECULAR_SETUP

            // -------------------------------------
            // Universal Pipeline keywords
            #pragma multi_compile _ _MAIN_LIGHT_SHADOWS _MAIN_LIGHT_SHADOWS_CASCADE _MAIN_LIGHT_SHADOWS_SCREEN
            #pragma multi_compile _ _ADDITIONAL_LIGHTS_VERTEX _ADDITIONAL_LIGHTS
            #pragma multi_compile_fragment _ _ADDITIONAL_LIGHT_SHADOWS
            #pragma multi_compile_fragment _ _REFLECTION_PROBE_BLENDING
            #pragma multi_compile_fragment _ _REFLECTION_PROBE_BOX_PROJECTION
            #pragma multi_compile_fragment _ _SHADOWS_SOFT
            #pragma multi_compile_fragment _ _SCREEN_SPACE_OCCLUSION
            #pragma multi_compile_fragment _ _DBUFFER_MRT1 _DBUFFER_MRT2 _DBUFFER_MRT3
            #pragma multi_compile_fragment _ _LIGHT_LAYERS
            #pragma multi_compile_fragment _ _LIGHT_COOKIES
            #pragma multi_compile _ _CLUSTERED_RENDERING

            // -------------------------------------
            // Unity defined keywords
            #pragma multi_compile _ LIGHTMAP_SHADOW_MIXING
            #pragma multi_compile _ SHADOWS_SHADOWMASK
            #pragma multi_compile _ DIRLIGHTMAP_COMBINED
            #pragma multi_compile _ LIGHTMAP_ON
            #pragma multi_compile _ DYNAMICLIGHTMAP_ON
            #pragma multi_compile_fog
            #pragma multi_compile_fragment _ DEBUG_DISPLAY

            //--------------------------------------
            // GPU Instancing
            #pragma multi_compile_instancing
            #pragma instancing_options renderinglayer
            #pragma multi_compile _ DOTS_INSTANCING_ON

            #pragma vertex LitPassVertex
            #pragma fragment LitPassFragment

            #include "Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal/Shaders/LitInput.hlsl"
            #include "Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal/Shaders/LitForwardPass.hlsl"
            ENDHLSL
        }

        Pass
        {
            Name "ShadowCaster"
            Tags{"LightMode" = "ShadowCaster"}

            ZWrite On
            ZTest LEqual
            ColorMask 0
            Cull[_Cull]

            HLSLPROGRAM
            #pragma exclude_renderers gles gles3 glcore
            #pragma target 4.5

            // -------------------------------------
            // Material Keywords
            #pragma shader_feature_local_fragment _ALPHATEST_ON
            #pragma shader_feature_local_fragment _SMOOTHNESS_TEXTURE_ALBEDO_CHANNEL_A

            //--------------------------------------
            // GPU Instancing
            #pragma multi_compile_instancing
            #pragma multi_compile _ DOTS_INSTANCING_ON

            // -------------------------------------
            // Universal Pipeline keywords

            // This is used during shadow map generation to differentiate between directional and punctual light shadows, as they use different formulas to apply Normal Bias
            #pragma multi_compile_vertex _ _CASTING_PUNCTUAL_LIGHT_SHADOW

            #pragma vertex ShadowPassVertex
            #pragma fragment ShadowPassFragment

            #include "Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal/Shaders/LitInput.hlsl"
            #include "Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal/Shaders/ShadowCasterPass.hlsl"
            ENDHLSL
        }

        Pass
        {
            // Lightmode matches the ShaderPassName set in UniversalRenderPipeline.cs. SRPDefaultUnlit and passes with
            // no LightMode tag are also rendered by Universal Render Pipeline
            Name "GBuffer"
            Tags{"LightMode" = "UniversalGBuffer"}

            ZWrite[_ZWrite]
            ZTest LEqual
            Cull[_Cull]

            HLSLPROGRAM
            #pragma exclude_renderers gles gles3 glcore
            #pragma target 4.5

            // -------------------------------------
            // Material Keywords
            #pragma shader_feature_local _NORMALMAP
            #pragma shader_feature_local_fragment _ALPHATEST_ON
            //#pragma shader_feature_local_fragment _ALPHAPREMULTIPLY_ON
            #pragma shader_feature_local_fragment _EMISSION
            #pragma shader_feature_local_fragment _METALLICSPECGLOSSMAP
            #pragma shader_feature_local_fragment _SMOOTHNESS_TEXTURE_ALBEDO_CHANNEL_A
            #pragma shader_feature_local_fragment _OCCLUSIONMAP
            #pragma shader_feature_local _PARALLAXMAP
            #pragma shader_feature_local _ _DETAIL_MULX2 _DETAIL_SCALED

            #pragma shader_feature_local_fragment _SPECULARHIGHLIGHTS_OFF
            #pragma shader_feature_local_fragment _ENVIRONMENTREFLECTIONS_OFF
            #pragma shader_feature_local_fragment _SPECULAR_SETUP
            #pragma shader_feature_local _RECEIVE_SHADOWS_OFF

            // -------------------------------------
            // Universal Pipeline keywords
            #pragma multi_compile _ _MAIN_LIGHT_SHADOWS _MAIN_LIGHT_SHADOWS_CASCADE _MAIN_LIGHT_SHADOWS_SCREEN
            //#pragma multi_compile _ _ADDITIONAL_LIGHTS_VERTEX _ADDITIONAL_LIGHTS
            //#pragma multi_compile _ _ADDITIONAL_LIGHT_SHADOWS
            #pragma multi_compile_fragment _ _REFLECTION_PROBE_BLENDING
            #pragma multi_compile_fragment _ _REFLECTION_PROBE_BOX_PROJECTION
            #pragma multi_compile_fragment _ _SHADOWS_SOFT
            #pragma multi_compile_fragment _ _DBUFFER_MRT1 _DBUFFER_MRT2 _DBUFFER_MRT3
            #pragma multi_compile_fragment _ _LIGHT_LAYERS
            #pragma multi_compile_fragment _ _RENDER_PASS_ENABLED

            // -------------------------------------
            // Unity defined keywords
            #pragma multi_compile _ LIGHTMAP_SHADOW_MIXING
            #pragma multi_compile _ SHADOWS_SHADOWMASK
            #pragma multi_compile _ DIRLIGHTMAP_COMBINED
            #pragma multi_compile _ LIGHTMAP_ON
            #pragma multi_compile _ DYNAMICLIGHTMAP_ON
            #pragma multi_compile_fragment _ _GBUFFER_NORMALS_OCT

            //--------------------------------------
            // GPU Instancing
            #pragma multi_compile_instancing
            #pragma instancing_options renderinglayer
            #pragma multi_compile _ DOTS_INSTANCING_ON

            #pragma vertex LitGBufferPassVertex
            #pragma fragment LitGBufferPassFragment

            #include "Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal/Shaders/LitInput.hlsl"
            #include "Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal/Shaders/LitGBufferPass.hlsl"
            ENDHLSL
        }

        Pass
        {
            Name "DepthOnly"
            Tags{"LightMode" = "DepthOnly"}

            ZWrite On
            ColorMask 0
            Cull[_Cull]

            HLSLPROGRAM
            #pragma exclude_renderers gles gles3 glcore
            #pragma target 4.5

            #pragma vertex DepthOnlyVertex
            #pragma fragment DepthOnlyFragment

            // -------------------------------------
            // Material Keywords
            #pragma shader_feature_local_fragment _ALPHATEST_ON
            #pragma shader_feature_local_fragment _SMOOTHNESS_TEXTURE_ALBEDO_CHANNEL_A

            //--------------------------------------
            // GPU Instancing
            #pragma multi_compile_instancing
            #pragma multi_compile _ DOTS_INSTANCING_ON

            #include "Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal/Shaders/LitInput.hlsl"
            #include "Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal/Shaders/DepthOnlyPass.hlsl"
            ENDHLSL
        }

        // This pass is used when drawing to a _CameraNormalsTexture texture
        Pass
        {
            Name "DepthNormals"
            Tags{"LightMode" = "DepthNormals"}

            ZWrite On
            Cull[_Cull]

            HLSLPROGRAM
            #pragma exclude_renderers gles gles3 glcore
            #pragma target 4.5

            #pragma vertex DepthNormalsVertex
            #pragma fragment DepthNormalsFragment

            // -------------------------------------
            // Material Keywords
            #pragma shader_feature_local _NORMALMAP
            #pragma shader_feature_local _PARALLAXMAP
            #pragma shader_feature_local _ _DETAIL_MULX2 _DETAIL_SCALED
            #pragma shader_feature_local_fragment _ALPHATEST_ON
            #pragma shader_feature_local_fragment _SMOOTHNESS_TEXTURE_ALBEDO_CHANNEL_A

            //--------------------------------------
            // GPU Instancing
            #pragma multi_compile_instancing
            #pragma multi_compile _ DOTS_INSTANCING_ON

            #include "Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal/Shaders/LitInput.hlsl"
            #include "Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal/Shaders/LitDepthNormalsPass.hlsl"
            ENDHLSL
        }

        // This pass it not used during regular rendering, only for lightmap baking.
        Pass
        {
            Name "Meta"
            Tags{"LightMode" = "Meta"}

            Cull Off

            HLSLPROGRAM
            #pragma exclude_renderers gles gles3 glcore
            #pragma target 4.5

            #pragma vertex UniversalVertexMeta
            #pragma fragment UniversalFragmentMetaLit

            #pragma shader_feature EDITOR_VISUALIZATION
            #pragma shader_feature_local_fragment _SPECULAR_SETUP
            #pragma shader_feature_local_fragment _EMISSION
            #pragma shader_feature_local_fragment _METALLICSPECGLOSSMAP
            #pragma shader_feature_local_fragment _ALPHATEST_ON
            #pragma shader_feature_local_fragment _ _SMOOTHNESS_TEXTURE_ALBEDO_CHANNEL_A
            #pragma shader_feature_local _ _DETAIL_MULX2 _DETAIL_SCALED

            #pragma shader_feature_local_fragment _SPECGLOSSMAP

            #include "Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal/Shaders/LitInput.hlsl"
            #include "Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal/Shaders/LitMetaPass.hlsl"

            ENDHLSL
        }

        Pass
        {
            Name "Universal2D"
            Tags{ "LightMode" = "Universal2D" }

            Blend[_SrcBlend][_DstBlend]
            ZWrite[_ZWrite]
            Cull[_Cull]

            HLSLPROGRAM
            #pragma exclude_renderers gles gles3 glcore
            #pragma target 4.5

            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag
            #pragma shader_feature_local_fragment _ALPHATEST_ON
            #pragma shader_feature_local_fragment _ALPHAPREMULTIPLY_ON

            #include "Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal/Shaders/LitInput.hlsl"
            #include "Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal/Shaders/Utils/Universal2D.hlsl"
            ENDHLSL
        }
    }

    SubShader
    {
        // Universal Pipeline tag is required. If Universal render pipeline is not set in the graphics settings
        // this Subshader will fail. One can add a subshader below or fallback to Standard built-in to make this
        // material work with both Universal Render Pipeline and Builtin Unity Pipeline
        Tags{"RenderType" = "Opaque" "RenderPipeline" = "UniversalPipeline" "UniversalMaterialType" = "Lit" "IgnoreProjector" = "True" "ShaderModel"="2.0"}
        LOD 300

        // ------------------------------------------------------------------
        //  Forward pass. Shades all light in a single pass. GI + emission + Fog
        Pass
        {
            // Lightmode matches the ShaderPassName set in UniversalRenderPipeline.cs. SRPDefaultUnlit and passes with
            // no LightMode tag are also rendered by Universal Render Pipeline
            Name "ForwardLit"
            Tags{"LightMode" = "UniversalForward"}

            Blend[_SrcBlend][_DstBlend]
            ZWrite[_ZWrite]
            Cull[_Cull]

            HLSLPROGRAM
            #pragma only_renderers gles gles3 glcore d3d11
            #pragma target 2.0

            //--------------------------------------
            // GPU Instancing
            #pragma multi_compile_instancing
            #pragma instancing_options renderinglayer

            // -------------------------------------
            // Material Keywords
            #pragma shader_feature_local _NORMALMAP
            #pragma shader_feature_local _PARALLAXMAP
            #pragma shader_feature_local _RECEIVE_SHADOWS_OFF
            #pragma shader_feature_local _ _DETAIL_MULX2 _DETAIL_SCALED
            #pragma shader_feature_local_fragment _SURFACE_TYPE_TRANSPARENT
            #pragma shader_feature_local_fragment _ALPHATEST_ON
            #pragma shader_feature_local_fragment _ALPHAPREMULTIPLY_ON
            #pragma shader_feature_local_fragment _EMISSION
            #pragma shader_feature_local_fragment _METALLICSPECGLOSSMAP
            #pragma shader_feature_local_fragment _SMOOTHNESS_TEXTURE_ALBEDO_CHANNEL_A
            #pragma shader_feature_local_fragment _OCCLUSIONMAP
            #pragma shader_feature_local_fragment _SPECULARHIGHLIGHTS_OFF
            #pragma shader_feature_local_fragment _ENVIRONMENTREFLECTIONS_OFF
            #pragma shader_feature_local_fragment _SPECULAR_SETUP

            // -------------------------------------
            // Universal Pipeline keywords
            #pragma multi_compile _ _MAIN_LIGHT_SHADOWS _MAIN_LIGHT_SHADOWS_CASCADE _MAIN_LIGHT_SHADOWS_SCREEN
            #pragma multi_compile _ _ADDITIONAL_LIGHTS_VERTEX _ADDITIONAL_LIGHTS
            #pragma multi_compile_fragment _ _ADDITIONAL_LIGHT_SHADOWS
            #pragma multi_compile_fragment _ _SHADOWS_SOFT
            #pragma multi_compile_fragment _ _SCREEN_SPACE_OCCLUSION
            #pragma multi_compile_fragment _ _DBUFFER_MRT1 _DBUFFER_MRT2 _DBUFFER_MRT3
            #pragma multi_compile_fragment _ _REFLECTION_PROBE_BLENDING
            #pragma multi_compile_fragment _ _REFLECTION_PROBE_BOX_PROJECTION
            #pragma multi_compile_fragment _ _LIGHT_LAYERS
            #pragma multi_compile_fragment _ _LIGHT_COOKIES
            #pragma multi_compile _ _CLUSTERED_RENDERING

            // -------------------------------------
            // Unity defined keywords
            #pragma multi_compile _ LIGHTMAP_SHADOW_MIXING
            #pragma multi_compile _ SHADOWS_SHADOWMASK
            #pragma multi_compile _ DIRLIGHTMAP_COMBINED
            #pragma multi_compile _ LIGHTMAP_ON
            #pragma multi_compile_fog
            #pragma multi_compile_fragment _ DEBUG_DISPLAY

            #pragma vertex LitPassVertex
            #pragma fragment LitPassFragment

            #include "Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal/Shaders/LitInput.hlsl"
            #include "Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal/Shaders/LitForwardPass.hlsl"
            ENDHLSL
        }

        Pass
        {
            Name "ShadowCaster"
            Tags{"LightMode" = "ShadowCaster"}

            ZWrite On
            ZTest LEqual
            ColorMask 0
            Cull[_Cull]

            HLSLPROGRAM
            #pragma only_renderers gles gles3 glcore d3d11
            #pragma target 2.0

            //--------------------------------------
            // GPU Instancing
            #pragma multi_compile_instancing

            // -------------------------------------
            // Material Keywords
            #pragma shader_feature_local_fragment _ALPHATEST_ON
            #pragma shader_feature_local_fragment _SMOOTHNESS_TEXTURE_ALBEDO_CHANNEL_A

            // -------------------------------------
            // Universal Pipeline keywords

            // This is used during shadow map generation to differentiate between directional and punctual light shadows, as they use different formulas to apply Normal Bias
            #pragma multi_compile_vertex _ _CASTING_PUNCTUAL_LIGHT_SHADOW

            #pragma vertex ShadowPassVertex
            #pragma fragment ShadowPassFragment

            #include "Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal/Shaders/LitInput.hlsl"
            #include "Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal/Shaders/ShadowCasterPass.hlsl"
            ENDHLSL
        }

        Pass
        {
            Name "DepthOnly"
            Tags{"LightMode" = "DepthOnly"}

            ZWrite On
            ColorMask 0
            Cull[_Cull]

            HLSLPROGRAM
            #pragma only_renderers gles gles3 glcore d3d11
            #pragma target 2.0

            //--------------------------------------
            // GPU Instancing
            #pragma multi_compile_instancing

            #pragma vertex DepthOnlyVertex
            #pragma fragment DepthOnlyFragment

            // -------------------------------------
            // Material Keywords
            #pragma shader_feature_local_fragment _ALPHATEST_ON
            #pragma shader_feature_local_fragment _SMOOTHNESS_TEXTURE_ALBEDO_CHANNEL_A

            #include "Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal/Shaders/LitInput.hlsl"
            #include "Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal/Shaders/DepthOnlyPass.hlsl"
            ENDHLSL
        }

        // This pass is used when drawing to a _CameraNormalsTexture texture
        Pass
        {
            Name "DepthNormals"
            Tags{"LightMode" = "DepthNormals"}

            ZWrite On
            Cull[_Cull]

            HLSLPROGRAM
            #pragma only_renderers gles gles3 glcore d3d11
            #pragma target 2.0

            #pragma vertex DepthNormalsVertex
            #pragma fragment DepthNormalsFragment

            // -------------------------------------
            // Material Keywords
            #pragma shader_feature_local _NORMALMAP
            #pragma shader_feature_local _PARALLAXMAP
            #pragma shader_feature_local _ _DETAIL_MULX2 _DETAIL_SCALED
            #pragma shader_feature_local_fragment _ALPHATEST_ON
            #pragma shader_feature_local_fragment _SMOOTHNESS_TEXTURE_ALBEDO_CHANNEL_A

            //--------------------------------------
            // GPU Instancing
            #pragma multi_compile_instancing

            #include "Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal/Shaders/LitInput.hlsl"
            #include "Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal/Shaders/LitDepthNormalsPass.hlsl"
            ENDHLSL
        }

        // This pass it not used during regular rendering, only for lightmap baking.
        Pass
        {
            Name "Meta"
            Tags{"LightMode" = "Meta"}

            Cull Off

            HLSLPROGRAM
            #pragma only_renderers gles gles3 glcore d3d11
            #pragma target 2.0

            #pragma vertex UniversalVertexMeta
            #pragma fragment UniversalFragmentMetaLit

            #pragma shader_feature EDITOR_VISUALIZATION
            #pragma shader_feature_local_fragment _SPECULAR_SETUP
            #pragma shader_feature_local_fragment _EMISSION
            #pragma shader_feature_local_fragment _METALLICSPECGLOSSMAP
            #pragma shader_feature_local_fragment _ALPHATEST_ON
            #pragma shader_feature_local_fragment _ _SMOOTHNESS_TEXTURE_ALBEDO_CHANNEL_A
            #pragma shader_feature_local _ _DETAIL_MULX2 _DETAIL_SCALED

            #pragma shader_feature_local_fragment _SPECGLOSSMAP

            #include "Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal/Shaders/LitInput.hlsl"
            #include "Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal/Shaders/LitMetaPass.hlsl"

            ENDHLSL
        }
        Pass
        {
            Name "Universal2D"
            Tags{ "LightMode" = "Universal2D" }

            Blend[_SrcBlend][_DstBlend]
            ZWrite[_ZWrite]
            Cull[_Cull]

            HLSLPROGRAM
            #pragma only_renderers gles gles3 glcore d3d11
            #pragma target 2.0

            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag
            #pragma shader_feature_local_fragment _ALPHATEST_ON
            #pragma shader_feature_local_fragment _ALPHAPREMULTIPLY_ON

            #include "Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal/Shaders/LitInput.hlsl"
            #include "Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal/Shaders/Utils/Universal2D.hlsl"
            ENDHLSL
        }
    }

    FallBack "Hidden/Universal Render Pipeline/FallbackError"
    CustomEditor "UnityEditor.Rendering.Universal.ShaderGUI.LitShader"
}
```

I haven't yet figured out any answers for this problem, since my knowledge of shaders is very limited and I managed to come up with this shader through some tutorials.